# Recursively apply function to object along a list of function arguments

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

This is a functional programming question using the purrrr package. I'm sure exactly how to express this question, but a simple example will show what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a string "ABCDEF", and I have a list of lists, with regexes and replacements for matching and substituting:

```
subs = list(
    A = list(regex = "A", sub = "a"),
    B = list(regex = "B", sub = "b"),
    C = list(regex = "C", sub = "c")
)
```

What I want to do, is take the string and apply the replacements with `stringr::str_replace_all` one after the other.

```
"ABCDEF" %>% 
    str_replace_all(subs$A$regex, subs$A$sub) %>% 
    str_replace_all(subs$B$regex, subs$B$sub) %>% 
    str_replace_all(subs$C$regex, subs$C$sub)

# "abcDEF"
```

Is there an extension of `reduce` or another higher order function I can use to do this? I know this can be achieved by looping through the list of replacements and mutating the string in place, but I am looking for a functional construct.

So ideally there would be some higher-order function `hof(.init, .x, .f, ...)` such that I can recursively apply a function to the string like so:

```
hof(.init = "ABCDEF", .x = subs,  ~ str_replace_all(.init, .x$regex, .x$sub))
```

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could find a purr equivalent to something like `Reduce(function(x, args) chartr(args$regex, args$sub, x), subs, init = "ABCDEF")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop and assign the output from each iteration to the object

```
for(i in seq_along(subs)) v1 <- str_replace_all(v1, subs[[i]]$regex, subs[[i]]$sub)
v1
#[1] "abcDEF"
```

---

As @alexis_laz mentioned in the comments, with `purrr` a similar function would be

```
library(purrr)
f1 <- function(x, args) str_replace_all(x, args$regex, args$sub)
reduce(.x = subs, .f = f1, .init = v1)
#[1] "abcDEF"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "ABCDEF"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I had actually tried this method (creating a binary function) but used `str_replace_all(x, args[["regex"]], args[["sub"]])` but this errorred out, which led me to think what I was trying didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reduce as you self mentioned like this

```
Reduce(function(l,r){str_replace_all(l,r$regex, r$sub)},subs,init = "ABCDEF")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach that doesn't actually uses the patterns and the replacements in a list format, but it saves them as vectors and then applies the `mgsub` command from package `qdap`.

```
library(qdap)
library(purrr)

# list of patterns and replacements
subs = list(
  A = list(regex = "A", sub = "a"),
  B = list(regex = "B", sub = "b"),
  C = list(regex = "C", sub = "c")
)

# get patterns and replacements as vectors from the list
subs_t = transpose(subs)
vec_pattern = unlist(subs_t$regex)
vec_replacement = unlist(subs_t$sub)


# apply function
mgsub(vec_pattern, vec_replacement, "ABCDEF")

# [1] "abcDEF"


# function also works with multiple texts
vec_text = c("ABCDEF", "FEDCBA")
mgsub(vec_pattern, vec_replacement, vec_text)

# [1] "abcDEF" "FEDcba"
```